# Map showing error in typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

[image]

**Error**

> property map does not exist on type observable

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `map` operator from `RxJS` like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

or just import all `RxJS` operators:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```